# How to install a language pack in Windows 7 Professional

Tags: windows-7, installation, language

How i can install any language for example Hebrew in Windows 7 Professional ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Only the Ultimate and Enterprise edition support changing the language through the control panel.

[Vistalizator](http://www.froggie.sk/index.html) provides the same functionality and supports all editions of Windows Vista and Windows 7.

Comment: Enterprise and Pro are the same versions. The only difference is enterprise is not sold to end users but to corporates.

Comment: I know but they are two different products and therefore I mentioned both.

Answer (score 2):

You can download from windows update the MUI of your choice and install it.
Links poining to windows update are available at http://www.froggie.sk/7lp64sp1.html for Windows 7 SP1 64 bits (other versions are one this website).

Answer (score 0):

I think that is an Ultimate feature - not in Pro.

Comment: You can install a language pack in Windows 7 Professional, however you can't do it through Windows Updates the way you can in Ultimate.

Comment: Free in Windows 7??? I had to pay 800$ for the language pack for Windows XP :(

Comment: @r0ca Free for Ultimate and Pro as far as I am aware.

Comment: I bought Windows 7 Ultimate yesterday. On the box it's saying Free 52 languages. Pro it's not included. But I was talking about XP

Comment: @Diago Interesting, I didn't know you could do that. Though not something I'd have bothered with anyway...I only need English! But that kind of reduces the difference between Pro and Ultimate.

Comment: @Grant. The differences between Ultimate and Pro is very small actually. I think it is mainly related to the languages and the Encryption features, although there is the MS nitpick list somewhere I am sure. I use Ultimate on my home machine and Pro/Enterprise everywhere else, and still haven't found something I can do with the one and not the other day to day.