# How to install a language pack in Windows 7 Home Premium, without upgrading to ultimate edition?

Tags: windows-7, language-pack

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install a language pack in Windows 7 Professional](https://superuser.com/questions/111309/how-to-install-a-language-pack-in-windows-7-professional)

I have a laptop with Windows 7 Home Premium.

How can I install language packs listed in [Download languages for Windows](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/languages), specifically I am interested in Tamil language

Is there anyway I can do this without upgrading to Ultimate edition ?

Comment: Don't think it can be done.  I know that you can type in Tamil, but to have everything displayed in that language, you'll need the Ultimate Edition of Windows 7.  (That is the only reason why I have Win 7 Ultimate.)

Comment: Actually, I think it is doable.  You may not be able to have multiple languages installed simultaneously, but I think you can get rid of English (or the default) and just use Tamil... If you told use what you wanted to do... What your primary reason for wanting the "Tamil Language Pack" was, we may be able to find you an alternative.

Comment: @soandos, its close, but not 100%, not an "exact duplicate".

Comment: @wizlog, the answers should be merged at best.

Comment: Do you have the rep for that?

Comment: I am not a mod, I can just mark it.

Comment: @wizlog i have a user who dont know much english and i want him to use the laptop so english menus, etc will be great.. is this enough information?

Answer (score 1):

No way to do it.
There are plenty of sites that will tell you to copy this or that DLL to System32 and bypass the check. This works until the next Windows update. the first thing it does is a checksum (or similar) of DLLs and libs. What follows immediately after that is that your system is marked as pirated, with annoying messages and degraded performance.

I've tried this once and it took me several hours on the phone with MS support and a complete Windows reinstallation to recover.

You either buy a local edition of the OS (which will have your language + English - but nothing else) or an Enterprise or Ultimate version. You can blame Microsoft for this crap. Tell them I sent you :)

Comment: It's possible. See accepted answer from this question http://superuser.com/questions/111309/how-to-install-a-language-pack-in-windows-7-professional

Comment: That solution uses an application that circumvents Windows license and policies. Expect it to be blocked or rendered useless. by a future update - if it hasn't already.

Comment: Still waiting for it to be blocked... It's a simple hack. They didn't block hacking windows xp mode into home premium either. Microsoft seems not to care since what they are selling isn't the _ability_ to do it; what they sell is the _convenience_.

Comment: Doesn't make it more legal. I do not like the MS licensing - allowing them to charge extra for a few DLLs - any more than the rest of you. But installing any feature, including a language pack, on a cheaper version violates license.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested lots of tools and options. The safest solutions are the following:

[Install & Change to a New Display Language in Windows 7 Home & Professional with Vistalizator](http://www.7tutorials.com/install-change-new-display-language-windows-7-home-professional-vistalizator)

[Install and Change to a New Display Language in Windows 7 Home and Professional Using Language Interface Packs](http://www.7tutorials.com/install-and-change-new-display-language-windows-7-home-and-professional)