# English doesn't apper as the display language in Windows 8. No download option available

Tags: windows-8, language-pack

I installed Windows 8 Pro edition Spanish version and I'd like to have English as the display language for Windows.

I follow the steps detailed in the solution but the option "Windows display language: Available for download" doesn't appear next to the English language as it does with Spanish.

I guess that English language is pre-installed with Windows 8 Pro.

It happens the same with the rest of the languages. You only can add the language as an input method and can't download it.

Maybe I can't set English language as the Display Language due to the license type of my Windows 8 SKU?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to have several languages in Windows 8?](http://superuser.com/questions/497982/is-it-possible-to-have-several-languages-in-windows-8) [this one](http://superuser.com/questions/111309/how-to-install-a-language-pack-in-windows-7-professional)

Comment: Is this a SingleLanguage edition?

Comment: Have you installed the English language pack?  If the information in this question does lead you to way to install the English language pack then you have a SKU that does not allow for multiple language packs to be installed. http://superuser.com/questions/497982/is-it-possible-to-have-several-languages-in-windows-8?rq=1

Comment: As I said, this is a Windows 8 Pro edition, not a Windows 8 Single Language edition, so there's the possibility to install multiple languages. I could install another language downloading it from the Microsoft site, but "main" languages don't allow to donwload them, I'm afraid that a few languages pack come pre-installed with Windows 8.

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/4/ne3q.jpg/

Comment: I changed the question's title and also some content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've able to sort out the issue but I think not in the most ideal way.

According to Microsoft, you should download additional languages pack through the *language preferences* view.

That's ok and quite easy, just add the additional language and download it. The problem comes, as happened in my case, when you add the language pack and doesn't appear the download option for that language, the new language is just available as an *Input method*

If you go to the Microsoft site for language pack downloads ([Language packs](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/language-packs#lptabs=win8)) and have a look at the *Download method* next to each language, you'll notice that many of the just can be download from the Control Panel, And the rest are available for direct download. On of them is the English language pack.

Looking on the Internet, I got the links for the English language pack and a few more from this site [All Windows 8 Language Packs](http://conocimientoadictivo.blogspot.com/2012/11/Descargar-Language-Packs-Windows-8-Links-Oficiales.html#more). The site is in Spanish, but it's not quite complicated find out the right link for your language pack. Download the file and follow the steps below the links.

After the LP installation, I see the *Windows display language* option and can use English US as the display language for my Windows 8 Pro.

Thank you.

Comment: That link is dead, but this one now works: http://winaero.com/blog/download-official-mui-language-packs-for-windows-8-1-windows-8-and-windows-7/

Comment: The same for Windows 10. You have a [link](http://winaero.com/blog/download-mui-language-pack-for-windows-10-build-14342-direct-links/) to download the language packs.